# Proving an Inequality with $2$ Variables

Tags: inequality

How would one go about proving that $x^2 - yx \leq 1 - y$ for $1 \leq x \leq y - 1$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 - yx \leq 1 - y
$
is the same as
$x^2 - 1 \leq yx - y
$
or
$(x-1)(x+1) \le y(x-1)
$.

This is true if $x = 1$.

If $x > 1$ we can divide by
$x-1$ to get
$x+1 \le y
$
which is one of our assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If   $y-1\ge x\ge1,$ then $x-1\ge0$ and $y-1-x\ge1\ge0,$ so $(x-1)(y-1-x)\ge0$.

Therefore, $xy-x-x^2-y+x+1=xy-x^2-y+1\ge0$.   Therefore, $1-y\ge x^2-xy$.